# Juniper network connect on Ubuntu 14.04 cannot find 32 bit Java

Tags: networking, software-installation, java, connection, openjdk

I have Ubuntu x64 and trying to install Juniper network connect.

Installed  64bit jre/jdk, icedtea and 32bit jre

```
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre icedtea-7-plugin
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre:i386
```

command  `update-alternatives --config java` shows that java-7-openjdk-i386 is intalled and selected

```
 Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java    1070      manual mode
```

But when I'm trying to install network connect recieved following error:

> "Setup failed. Please install 32 bit Java and update alternatives
>   links using update-alternatives command. For more details, refer KB
>   article KB25230 "

These steps worked fine on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and I'm wondering why it doesn't work on 14.04

Comment: I've just worked out the solution before finding this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450369/how-to-install-juniper-vpn-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: adding symlink to /usr/sbin/ helped.

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/update-alternatives /usr/sbin/`

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

adding symlink to /usr/sbin/ helped.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/update-alternatives /usr/sbin/
```

solution from following article:
**[How to install Juniper VPN on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450369/how-to-install-juniper-vpn-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another note to help anyone having problems...

The best thing you can do for debugging problems is to turn on the Java console in IcedTea by running itweb-settings - this will show all the errors in the juniper script.

In my case the script was running 'java -version' and grepping for 'Java version' but I was using openjdk which outputs 'openjdk version'. So I installed the Oracle jre 8 and created a symlink to the plugin in my .mozilla/plugins directory.

Answer (score -1):

the juniper documents say to keep 64bit as a default

unfortuneatly the doco is behind their firewall (an account is free)

http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB25230&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1400682188393