# Can't get Juniper working on Ubuntu 14.04 The pieces work but whole does not

Tags: 14.04, vpn

I really need some help troubleshooting this.

I've been here already:

[How to install Juniper VPN on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450369/how-to-install-juniper-vpn-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

http://mad-scientist.us/juniper.html

The client opens and then closes. It runs fine from the command line but doesn't connect to anything.

Firewall is down:

```
user@box:~$ firewall
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 21770 packets, 3492K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 22171 packets, 1501K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
user@box:~$
```

As far as I can tell all of the 32 bit packages are installed. I'm seeing no Exceptions or warnings that suggest one might be missing. Do I know all the places to look for these? No, probably not, but I have:

```
user@box ~ $ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 zlib1g:i386 libgtk2-perl libwww-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libwww-perl is already the newest version.
libgtk2-perl is already the newest version.
zlib1g:i386 is already the newest version.
libc6:i386 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

...and also:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for user: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java    1070      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

When started from CLI:

```
user@box:~$ sudo msjnc --connect --root 
Enter your password or PID+SecureID: 
Connecting to vpn.company.com (company) ................................. failed
The Juniper Network Connect VPN session did not start.
```

Also:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java -classpath /home/user/.juniper_networks/network_connect/NC.jar NC ncui -h vpn.company.com -n -t -x
```

The above command pops up the window and it does prompt for a password but it drops dead when I enter it. What I'm afraid of is that there might be an additional password that I don't know of, similar to Cisco VPN networking.

The `update-alternatives` link has been created in `/usr/sbin`.

Comment: Did you verify you have the correct VPN address?  In my case, if i go to vpn.company.com, it launches network connect and connects. But, if i use network connect without it or use it from mac/linux i need to use a different address.
Also, are you using the right username with Domain/username?

Comment: Well, if it's a different address, then I need to know what it is but my searches here haven't turned up any alternatives. Same with the creds, if they are not what I expect, then I need to get them from somebody.  I'll check on that on Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Juniper connection tools can't run on an encrypted partition. This is what I was experiencing. IMHO, this is completely ludicrous.