# Juniper on 64bit 16.04?

Tags: java, 16.04, 64-bit

I am having the exact problem described at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450369/how-to-install-juniper-vpn-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts), but in 64bit 16.04 LTS instead.  That is, when I try to run the Juniper VPN from my company web site, I get the successive messages

"Please ensure that necessary 32 bit libraries are installed. For more details, refer KB article KB25230"

"Setup failed. Please install 32 bit Java and update alternatives links using update-alternatives command. For more details, refer KB article KB25230"

The links to "KB article KB25230" are broken.  I tried the accepted answer at the linked question, but it didn't help.  I also tried manually selecting 32bit java with "update-alternatives --config java".  Is there anything new in 16.04 that has to be done?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too until I installed 32-bit java7 (which is not provided by default in the 16.04 repositories; they have java8).

I grabbed an old unsupported one from oracle; there is hopefully a nicer way to do it via the package manager and openJDK but I just needed to get things working.

So I think it is an issue with the VPN software not liking java8.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried installing openjdk-7-jre:i386 using a ppa as [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761127/ubuntu-16-04-and-openjdk-7), and also the oracle-java7-installer from a different ppa as [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04), but neither worked; they get farther, but after the VPN window pops up and shows "connecting" it crashes.  Possibly the oracle-java7-installer is 64-bit?  I can't tell, but there is no ":i386" in the ppa.  Where did you get your 32-bit oracle java7?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/7u79-b15/jdk-7u79-linux-i586.tar.gz
It is not going to get security updates so I was hoping to get something that is supported... Odd to have a security product that needs an insecure installation in order to work...

Comment: Thanks.  Apologies for the dumb question, but how do I install it?  The tgz has bin, lib, man, and plugin directories, but it doesn't look like everything is meant to be copied into /usr/local for instance.