# Juniper VPN doesn't work after Ubuntu 16.04 update

Tags: 16.04, updates, vpn

The VPN used to work properly even after upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. However after the major update I get "*JRE not installed/Java is disabled*" both in Firefox and Chromium.

I checked the link /usr/bin/update-alternatives is in place, java32 is installed. I even tried to re-install these packages

> sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5
>   lib32bz2-1.0 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxi6:i386

as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450369/how-to-install-juniper-vpn-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts), but they are up-to-date. From this list only libstdc++6 has been updated (apt-get dist-upgrade):

> libstdc++6:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2,
>   5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4),libstdc++6:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)

but I'm not sure how that affect Java visibility

There is a huge list of other updated packages in the /var/log/apt/history.log, and it's hard to identify which one caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by installing a solution that runs juniper on Ubuntu  without browser. The installation steps can be found [here](http://mad-scientist.us/juniper.html) and [here](https://gist.github.com/zamaterian/6681534).
Basically one need a .juniper_networks to be in home directory, a **msjnc** perl script and to set up connection settings (login/password).